# Cygwin missing include directories

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

So, I've been trying to get Eclipse with C++ to work on my computer. I've updated java, installed the JDK, installed MinGW and Cygwin, and installed the CDT. I've also added the necessary include directories.

...except some of the directories simply weren't there, which I assume is the cause for some issues I'm experiencing on C++ Eclipse.

Based on [this site's](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html) instructions, the missing includes are all the ones in the Cygwin directory. There is no mingw32 folder anywhere in my Cygwin installation.

I'm not sure why this is, but I need to know what to do about this. If it helps any, I'm on Windows 10, MinGW 4.9.3, and Cygwin 2.4.1.

Comment: MinGW/Msys and Cygwin are usually used independently.  Notice the disjunction" "MinGW **or** Cygwin" everywhere in the article you linked. What are you trying to achieve exactly? What includes are missing? Do you have GCC installed in Cygwin package manager (setup.exe)?

Comment: @Drop: In that website, it had two sections below the red text about the unresolved include: For Cygwin GCC and For MinGW GCC.  Step two of the latter said to have the includes be of my cygwin installation.

Comment: Actually, everything should work fine as long as you have `bin` folders in your `%PATH%`. Another thing is that Eclipse CDT is really terrible IDE to start with (well, my opinion). There are better tools exist, such as CLion and QtCreator. And of course there is Visual Studio. Make sure you try all of them! ;)

Comment: I have posted your solution as an answer proper. Would you accept it, or copy it and accept that if you'd like the attribution? Thanks.

Comment: I accept it. :) Got no problem with having the solution moved from the OP into the Answers section.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Turns out that the website had a typo under the section describing the include directories for the MinGW compiler. It had step 2 say " 'Add' the following directories to "GNU C++", where $MINGW_HOME is your Cygwin installed directory:"...

...when it should have said "MinGW" instead of "Cygwin".

So, with that mistake fixed, Eclipse stopped complaining about include directory issues.